# oracle SQL query Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```
SELECT SHIP.SHIPID, SHIP.SHIPID_SFX, SHIP.DATE_SOURCE, SHIP.DATE_SHIP, SHIP.WT_TOTAL, SHIP.LINK, SHIP.CARR,
MBSH.MB_ID, MBSH.MB_ID_SFX
, FBIL.DATE_BILL, FBIL.DATE_CHECK, FBIL.STATUS
FROM SHIP,
     MBSH,
    SFXR,
     FBIL
WHERE SHIP.DATE_SOURCE Between '2012/08/31' And '2012/09/28' 
AND SUBSTR(SHIP.CARR,1,1) = 'C'
AND substr(SHIP.CARR,2,1) between '0' and '9' 
And SHIP.CARR not in ('7','41','11','15')
AND SHIP.MOVE_MB Is Null 
AND SHIP.SOURCE03='JDE'
And MBSH.MB_SHIPID_SFX = SHIP.SHIPID_SFX
AND MBSH.MB_SHIPID = SHIP.SHIPID
And SFXR.SHIPID = SHIP.SHIPID
And SFXR.SHIPID_SFX = SHIP.SHIPID_SFX
And SFXR.CARR = SHIP.CARR
And FBIL.BILL_ID = SFXR.BILL_ID
And FBIL.BILL_BD = SFXR.BILL_BD
```

This is my query joining 4 tables. the sfxr table holds refrence to the ship and bill table. need to use it to get bill data using ship data. The above query runs forever. Can it be optimized or needs to be done through the application code.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have proper indexes set up

Comment: analyze all your tables used in query and try to run query again.

Comment: What is the column `SHIP.CARR`? You might replace the three `WHERE` conditions with one:  `where substr(SHIP.CARR,1,2) between 'C0' and 'C9'`.  Also, see if using dashes intead of slashes in your date constants helps (like `'2012-08-31'`.

Comment: Consider learning the ANSI join syntax, it won't help the speed but it will do wonders for the readability.

Answer (score 0):

First clean up

convert the parameters to dates

```
SHIP.DATE_SOURCE Between '2012/08/31' And '2012/09/28'    
SHIP.DATE_SOURCE Between to_date('2012/08/31','YYYY/MM/DD') And to_date('2012/09/28','YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Drop the NOT IN the values do not start with 'C' so it's dedundant. Use the between as Bob suggested.

```
AND SUBSTR(SHIP.CARR,1,1) = 'C'    
AND substr(SHIP.CARR,2,1) between '0' and '9'       
-- AND SHIP.CARR not in ('7','41','11','15')
```

For us to be able to help you we need you to do the following:

1. run statistic on the database (maybee use histograms).
2. Show us the indexes you have defined on the table
3. Then show us an explain plan